# Jhipster connexion to Mysql database in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jhipster

How to connect on my mysql database in application.yml of my jhipster application?

Here are my docker informations:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expose your docker port to host network by adding - - net=host to your docker run command. Then your application can access it like localhost:YourPort

Eg

```
   Docker run mysql --net=host
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the way to do it.

- download postgres image : docker pull postgres:alpine
- creat a docker database and pricised which port to connect to out of docker:
  docker run --name myUserName -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine
- go into docker container: docker exec -it containerID bash
- connect to postresql : psql -U postgres myUserName
- create a database: create database databaseName;
- now outside of docker, in your application.yml:
  datasource:
  type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bnksearch?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

  username: postgres

  password: postgres

  hikari:

  ```
  poolName: Hikari

  auto-commit: false

  data-source-properties:

    cachePrepStmts: true

    prepStmtCacheSize: 250

    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048

    useServerPrepStmts: true
  ```